# Is there anething like @-quoted string in Actionscript?

Tags: c#, flash, string, actionscript

For example in C#
[@-quoted string literals start with @ and are enclosed in double quotation marks...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

So Is there anething like @-quoted string in Actionscript?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You can use double quotes easy enough within single quotes to delimit a string(e.g. '"Ahoy!" cried the captain.') if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is AS3 then you may get somewhere by declaring your literal as an XML CDATA section and then reading it back as a string. Others have posted this on SO, to allow multiline strings in AS3. Here's a web link about it:

http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/05/15/multi-line-strings-in-actionscript-3

HTH